# not able to read Manifest.xml when using <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

Tags: android, sms, sos

I am incorporating a button which will send an sms to a fixed no. when pressed. I have done the code but when I am incorporating

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

the app is failing to launch.

### logCat error

```
01-16 21:13:56.211: I/zipro(1814): Found Zip archive, but it looks empty
01-16 21:13:56.211: D/asset(1814): failed to open Zip archive '/data/local/tmp/CaravanSmartApp.apk'
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/CaravanSmartApp.apk
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:488)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:456)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:758)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:173)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
01-16 21:13:56.215: W/PackageParser(1814):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-16 21:13:56.219: W/DefContainer(1814): Failed to parse package
01-16 21:13:56.219: W/ActivityManager(472): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/CaravanSmartApp.apk
01-16 21:13:56.247: D/dalvikvm(472): GC_EXPLICIT freed 172K, 29% free 9573K/13364K, paused 3ms+1ms, total 28ms
01-16 21:13:56.251: D/AndroidRuntime(2767): Shutting down VM
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.caravansmartapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gps3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.osman.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" >
    </uses-feature>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBk7K5mdzkD8OJwGS8bvhLkmHJXxdxxxx" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.caravansmartapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.caravansmartapp.LocationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.caravansmartapp.ContactActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.caravansmartapp.SMSActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onSOS(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SMSActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }
```

### SMSActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class SMSActivity extends Activity{


    Button buttonSend;
    Intent intent;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String phoneNo = "9903070000";
            String sms = "Hi...This is test";

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,sms,null,null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
    }
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Please confirm that you have your manifest titled "AndroidManifest.xml". This is the exact name that the PackageManager is looking for in order to install your apk.

Comment: yes..the name is AndroidManifest.xml. I am updating in the query. I may have wrote the name in short in a hurry.

Comment: Hmmm, according to the logcat the PackageManager cannot find your AndroidManifest.xml, so you should investigate around this area. In your IDE workspace, open the apk on your computer (it's just a zip file) and make sure that the AndroidManifest.xml file exists there in the base folder.

Comment: If I remove <uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS”/> from the manifest its working fine.